# Numpy equivalent code to Octave's pinv(A) (pseudo-inverse)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm absolutely pulling my hair out here when trying to port over a matrix calculation from octave to numpy. This is specifically in regards to multivariate regression.

My arbitrary data is as follows where the array 'x' is my input value:

```
x = [
[1, 1 ,2], 
[1, 3 ,4],
[1, 5 ,6], 
[1, 7, 8],
[1, 9 ,10],
[1, 11 ,12]]
```

And 'y' are my output values (simply the sum):

```
y = [[3],[7],[11],[15],[19],[23]]
```

In Octave the following code will calculate the correct coefficients (where `pinv(A)` calculates the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of matrix A):

```
pinv (x' * x) * x' * y'
```

In numpy I am performing the following :

```
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
x_T = (x.transpose())
x_theta = (inv(np.dot(x_T,x)))
x_theta = np.dot(x_theta,x_T)
x_theta = np.dot(x_theta,y)
```

However this outputs:

```
[[-330.5],[36.875],[-3.875]]
```

Which is obviously incorrect. Presuming I'm just being simple but any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: What is `inv` here? I would use `np.linalg.pinv`. When I do that, your code seems to work for me

Comment: I was using np.linalg.inv but of course it makes sense to use pinv. Thanks so much for your help, Nathan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as an answer so your question doesn't still show up as unanswered - use `np.linalg.pinv` (pseudo-inverse) where you would use `pinv` in Octave.